# How do I make a plot using cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot a function of the form $z(r,\theta)$ where $r \in [0, R]$ for a finite R, $\theta \in [0,2\pi[$, and z is the third coordinate, a function of the first two. I couldn't find anything to do it natively, so I went back to Cartesian coordinates. But the result does not satisfy me, because the range of x is a function of y, a consequence of the constraint $ x^2+y^2 < R^2$. Is there already something in *Mathematica* to handle this kind of plot?

Comment: Have you tried RevolutionPlot3D?

Comment: @David That's a nice idea when $z$ is independent of $\theta$, but how do you propose using `RevolutionPlot3D` when $z$ does vary with $\theta$?

Comment: @whuber: Of course you're right. I didn't read the question too carefully.

Comment: @whuber, you can still use `RevolutionPlot[]` for the purpose. Witness for instance `RevolutionPlot3D[r^2 Cos[3 t], {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 3 π/2}]`. Of course, it's more enlightening to use `ParametricPlot3D[]` instead, as in your answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Do it parametrically.**  Here's a generic implementation:

```
cylinderPlot3D[f_, {rMin_, rMax_}, {tMin_, tMax_}, opts___] := 
   ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t], f[r, t]}, {r, rMin, rMax}, {t, tMin, tMax}, opts]
```

For example,

```
f[r_, t_] := r^2 Cos[3 t];
cylinderPlot3D[f, {0, 1}, {0, 2 Pi}, Mesh->None, Boxed->False]
```

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
RevolutionPlot3D[ f[r,t], {r, rmax, rmin}, {t, tmax, tmin}]
```