# Circular membrane vibration simulation

Tags: plotting, functions, manipulate, simulation

I'm new in *Mathematica* and I'm trying to simulate the [vibration of a circular membrane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrations_of_a_circular_membrane) for math project but I don't even know how to start.

The wave equation describes the displacement of the membrane $(z)$ as a function of its position $(r,\theta)$ and time $(t)$.

$$
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial t^2}=c^2 \nabla^2 z
$$

For an ordinary circular drumhead the imposed boundary conditions are that $z$ is $2π$ periodic, finite within $0 ≤ r ≤ a$ and at $r = a$ (the edge of the drum) the displacement is zero: $z(a) = 0$. The wave equation is solved through a method of separation of variables and produces the solution:

$$
z=A_{nj}J_n\left(\frac{\omega r}{c}\right)\sin(\omega t+\phi)\sin(n\theta+\varphi)
$$

How can I simulate/plot this solution in Mathematica?

Comment: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Courseware/7946/A_Vibrating_Circular_Membrane.nb?file_id=7531

Comment: Or, you can use [finite elements](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56305/52) to programmatically generate the eigenfunctions.

Comment: The answer to your question about plotting can be found here: [How do I make a 3DPlot using cylindrical coordinates?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19076).  You'll have to choose numbers for your parameters, of course.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a 3DPlot using cylindrical coordinates?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19076/how-do-i-make-a-3dplot-using-cylindrical-coordinates)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't think this is precisely a duplicate because the question also requires using `BesselJZero` to satisfy the boundary conditions. I may try to quickly write an answer, not using 3D plot but 2D plot instead, to make it a bit more "different" from the linked question.

Comment: @jens It's possible I don't understand.  It seems the only difference is possibly animating over `t`.  Presumably the OP knows how to determine $c$, since they don't ask about it.

Comment: Side note: As of _v10.3_, the problem can be resolved straightforwardly with `DEigensystem` and `NDEigensystem`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The separation-of-variables solution you quoted has two indices appearing in it: `n` and `j` (the subscripts of the coefficient $A_{nj}$). Here, `n` is azimuthal mode order, i.e. it counts the number of nodes along the direction in which the polar-angle $\theta$ varies (divided by 2).

The index `j` is needed because the wave is supposed to satisfy the boundary condition of being zero at the radius `a`. Here, it's best to employ `a` as the unit of length, so that `r=1` is the radius of the circle, and the boundary condition becomes

$$J_{n}(\frac{\omega_j}{c}) = 0$$

Here, I added the index `j` to the frequency, because only a discrete set of $\omega_j$ can satisfy the above equation.

To determine these allowed frequencies, you can use [`BesselJZero`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BesselJZero.html).

For the plot, I'll convert the polar coordinate form of the separated solution to Cartesian coordinates. This is done by defining the function `fXY` below. It takes the index `n` and the wave number $k_j\equiv\omega_j/c$ as inputs. I'll leave out the time dependent factor for now, i.e., consider only the spatial variation of the wave at a given fixed time. Also, I'll choose the phase $\phi$ of the azimuthal solution to be such that I get a cosine instead of a sine:

```
fXY[n_, k_][x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 BesselJ[n, k Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]] Cos[n ArcTan[y, x]]
```

Now do the plot, given a pair of indices `{n, j}`:

```
wavePattern[n_, j_] := Module[
  {k0 = N[BesselJZero[n, j]]},
  DensityPlot[fXY[n, k0][x, y],
   {x, -1.1, 1.1}, {y, -1.2, 1.1},
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 < 1],
   ColorFunction -> "BlueGreenYellow",
   PlotPoints -> 100,
   MaxRecursion -> 0, 
   Epilog -> 
    Inset[Grid[{{"n", n}, {"j", j}}, Frame -> All], {-.9, .9}],
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial"}]
  ]
```

I count the index `j` starting at `1` because there is always at least one radial node (at the boundary).

As an example, here are some plots:

```
Show[GraphicsGrid@Table[wavePattern[m, n], {m, 0, 2}, {n, 1, 3}], 
 ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image: plots]

In the `DensityPlot` inside the function `wavePattern`, I set the option `MaxRecursion -> 0` to speed up the plotting. An additional ingredient in making the plot for this solution is the use of `RegionFunction` to define the circular domain of the wave.

Since I left out the time dependence, it may be better to apply a color scheme that emphasizes the **nodal** lines, because these lines are the only thing that stays constant in time for a standing wave such as this. So here is an alternative plotting  function:

```
wavePattern[n_, j_] := 
 Module[{k0 = N[BesselJZero[n, j]]}, 
  DensityPlot[fXY[n, k0][x, y], {x, -1.1, 1.1}, {y, -1.2, 1.1}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 < 1], 
   ColorFunction -> 
    Function[{x}, 
     Blend[{White, Darker@Brown, White}, 2 ArcTan[10 x]/Pi + .5]], 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, 
   MaxRecursion -> 0, 
   Epilog -> 
    Inset[Grid[{{"n", n}, {"j", j}}, Frame -> All], {-.9, .9}], 
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial"}]]

Show[GraphicsGrid@Table[wavePattern[m, n], {m, 0, 2}, {n, 1, 3}], 
 ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image: nodes]

This is pretty close to the kind of pattern you would *actually observe* if you took a vibrating plate and spread sand on it: the grains will move to the places in the standing wave where the amplitude remains zero at all times, i.e., the nodes. That's what is shown in brown above.

Comment: +1 Nice visualizations as usual.  In any case, it seems good to have this standard PDE example on the site, esp. since it's not in the documentation (or at least, I can't find it).

Comment: Great!!! Thank you very much Jens! How can I make 3D plots using this method?

Comment: To make a 3D plot, just take the first definition of `wavePattern` and replace `DensityPlot` by `Plot3D`. You may want to omit the `Epilog` and `BaseStyle` options, too.