# Rotating an Interpolating Function

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, rotation, geometric-transform

I have used the following code to generate eigenfunctions of a PDE:

```
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] 
    Polygon[{{-1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}, {-1/2, 1/2}}], 4];
```

By applying `funs[[3]]`you can see that the third eigenfunction is an interpolating function:

[image: Interpolating Function]

With contour plot:

[image: Plot of third eigenfunction]

What I now wish to do is to transform this function by rotating it anticlockwise by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ about the origin.

Let's say that the points lying on our eigenfunction are $(x,y,f(x,y))$.

I now wish to effectively move these points by perhaps taking $(x,y) \mapsto (y,-x)$

I cannot seem to find anything online to describe how to do this for these interpolating functions.

I tried defining a function R and applying it to funs[[3]] with no success.

```
R := Function[g, g /. Thread[{x, y} -> ({y,-x})]]
```

I thought that this may work as it would replace the coordinates for me, but I now know that my logic is flawed.

Please note: I am not asking how to rotate the contourplot (even though a contour plot of the transformed eigenfunction should look identical to it) I would like a transformation to be applied to the function because I intend to use it later on.

I would be really grateful if somebody could help me on this - I've been playing around with code for the past three hours.

Comment: Can't test on mobile, but what about simply f[y, - x]? Where f is the initial interpolating function.

Comment: Doing so doesn't give off an error but the contour plot is blank. This might be my fault though - I'm very new to mathematica.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your approach (with is essentially from [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/105277/245)), as you can see by calling `R[funs[[1]]]`. You just have to watch out whether you have an object with `Head` of `InterpolationFunction` or not. What your solver returns is an interpolating function, **evaluated** at a symbolic argument (not the actual function!). In rotating it, you have to **replace** the symbolic arguments by rotated versions. For what you're after, it may be better to change `NDEigensystem` by replacing `u[x,y]` with  `u` in argument 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
rotation = {x, y}.{{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {-Sin[t], Cos[t]}};
f[t_] = funs[[3]] /. {x -> rotation[[1]], y -> rotation[[2]]};
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[f[t], {x, -.3, .3}, {y, -.3, .3}], {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really good but unfortunately I keep getting the error 'Tag Plus in (Sin[x]+Sin[y])[t_] is Protected'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a definition  of `f` before. `Clear[f]` or used different symbol.

Comment: Silly me - you were right! It's all working now. Could I ask why you've indexed as `rotation[[1]]` and `rotation[[2]]`? Thanks

Comment: `rotation` is a vector and the first component has to be in position of `x` and the second component has to be in position of `y` (look at the `[x,y]` at the end of your function).

Answer (score 8):

You can use `RotationTransform`.

```
With[{rot = funs[[3]] /. Inner[Rule, {x, y}, RotationTransform[π/2][{x, y}], List]},
 ContourPlot[rot, {x, -.5, .5}, {y, -.5, .5}]
]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

---

Also with `Manipulate`

```
Manipulate[
 With[{rot = funs[[3]] /. Inner[Rule, {x, y}, RotationTransform[θ][{x, y}], List]},
  Quiet@ContourPlot[rot, {x, -.5, .5}, {y, -.5, .5}]],
 Column[{
   AngularGauge[Dynamic@θ, {0, 2 π}, 
    ScaleOrigin -> {0, 2 π}, ScaleDivisions -> {8, 2}, 
    TargetUnits -> "Radians", GaugeLabels -> "Radians"]}],
 ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: This also works perfectly! Thank you so much