# How can I plot a surface in cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: plotting, homework

The surface I want to plot is $z^2 + r^2 = 25\, \theta$.

Please tell me how to do it in Mathematica.

Comment: `ContourPlot3D`?

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher How would you write the function?

Comment: That depends. What is $z$, $r$, $\theta$? I guess you try to express an equation in cylindrical coordinates... but who knows?

Comment: See, for instance, the first example in [`TransformedField`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedField.html). You can then apply `ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@TransformedField[..],...]`

Answer (score 2):

Brandon: You could modify the example given in:
[How do I make a 3DPlot using cylindrical coordinates?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19076/how-do-i-make-a-3dplot-using-cylindrical-coordinates) as follows:

```
cylinderPlot3D[f_, {rMin_, rMax_}, {\[Theta]Min_, \[Theta]Max_},opts___] :=ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[\[Theta]], r Sin[\[Theta]],f[r, \[Theta]]}, {r, rMin, rMax}, {\[Theta], \[Theta]Min, \[Theta]Max}, opts]

g[r_, \[Theta]_] := Sqrt[25 \[Theta] - r^2];

cylinderPlot3D[g, {0, 1}, {0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> True]
```